# jqplot and rendering it with asp.net mvc model

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-3, jqplot

In my asp.net mvc 3.0 app, I am gonna draw a chart which its X-axis contains date values and y-axis contains views per day. For chart drawing I use [jqplot date-axes](http://www.jqplot.com/tests/date-axes.php) , and I am passing it json result. here is the model :

```
 public class MyDateModel
    {
        public string Date { get; set; }
        public int Views { get; set; }
    }
```

and here is the action :

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var res = new List<MyDateModel>();

            res.Add(new MyDateModel { Date=DateTime.Now.AddDays(-9).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm"),Views=10});
            res.Add(new MyDateModel { Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-3).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm"), Views = 3 });
            res.Add(new MyDateModel { Date = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm"), Views = 3 });

            return View(res);
        }
```

and finally the view:

```
@model IEnumerable<Chartjquery_jqplot.Models.MyDateModel>
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Index</title>
    <link href="../../Content/jquery.jqplot.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery.jqplot.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/jqplot.dateAxisRenderer.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/jqplot.json2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            var jsonurl=@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
            var plot2 = $.jqplot('chart2', jsonurl, {
                title: "AJAX JSON Data Renderer",
                axes:{xaxis:{renderer:$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer}}

            });




        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))
        <div id="chart2" style="height: 300px; width: 500px;">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

But It does not draw any thing on page.

Would you help me please ?

Besides the json result is :

[{"Date":"2012-07-06 12:10","Views":10},{"Date":"2012-07-12 12:10","Views":3},{"Date":"2012-07-15 12:10","Views":3}]

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to pass correct json data to chart. Here is the html hepler I wrote :

```
public static MvcHtmlString GetStrippedJson(this HtmlHelper helper,string json)
        {
            json=json.Replace("\"Date\":", string.Empty);

            json=json.Replace("\"Views\":", string.Empty);

            json=json.Replace('}', ']');

            json=json.Replace('{', '[');

            return MvcHtmlString.Create(json);
        }
```

but I dont know how to set tick inter val based on daily ticks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps, but my code for passing data was the following.  @Model.data is a List.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var data = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@Model.data));
        //debugger;
        //alert(data);
        $.jqplot('chartdiv', data);
```